# How do I have unicode characters on GitHub shown as characters rather than icons?

Tags: github, unicode, icons, markdown, glyph

I decided to write the name of [this plugin of mine](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap) as `vim↪softwrap` rather than `vim-softwrap`, but, to my surprise, GitHub shows the `↪` as an icon:

[image]

What can I do to avoid that?

---

I'm not sure whether it's GitHub that is doing it or it's the Markdown specification to require it.

Comment: A part the considerations that a name is not a logo, but Unicode provide you variant selector. Just use the "text" one. It doesn't guarantee that the emoji version is not used, but more often then not the variant selectors are followed. For sure I'll never be able to use your plugin (the position of the character doesn't help tab completion to help me)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, what do you mean by _the position of the character doesn't help tab completion to help me_? Are you referring to tab-completing while showing the soft-wrapped line?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's using these fonts (the css selector being the `<g-emoji>` tag that it inserts around emoji unicode):

```css
g-emoji {
    font-family: "Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

If you save this as an html file an open it, you will see the same thing:

```html
<p style='font-family: "Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol"'>↪</p>
```